# Restoring Database in local node Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, backup, nodes, nosql

Regards community,

I have the files (folders in a usb) from a cassandra database such as: /var/lib/cassandra/data/**keyspace_name/table_name1/table_name2**, and I want to know the way/process to restore in my local cassandra node.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straight forward. Use cqlsh to log onto your local Cassandra node, create the same schema (`describe schema` from node your copying) and copy the data from your `table_name1` dir to:

```
data_dir/keyspace_name/table_name1/*
```

on local system. for each table.

Comment: Does'nt work                                                                                                               cqlsh> USE keyspace_name;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Keyspace 'keyspace_name' does not exist"   This is my step by step:  1. sudo service cassandra stop (local node) 2.  sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/* (local node) 3. sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/*   4 .sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*  5. sudo cp -r /media/usb/kyspace_name /var/lib/cassandra/data/                              What am I doing wrong?     Thank you

Comment: did you `CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_name ...` ? as part of the "Create the same schema"

Comment: Yes, but only the keyspace_name, I can't create the column family (tables) because  I don't know these. I mean, I don't know how it is built the database for that reason I want to restore.    Thank you a lot